# Robot Framework - Run Keyword If

Tags: robotframework

I have a clarification on "Run Keyword If" command.
The command works if it is assigned to some variable as shown:

```
${txt}=    Run Keyword If    ${lenght} > 5    Some Keyword  
...    ELSE IF    ${lenght} < 5    Some Keyword  
...    ELSE    Some Keyword  
Log       ${txt}
```

If I use the command as shown, it is not working, it is taking the "ELSE IF" statements as arguments to the "Some Keyword"

```
Run Keyword If    ${lenght} > 5    Some Keyword                                                              
...    ELSE IF    ${lenght} < 5    Some Keyword  
...    ELSE    Some Keyword
```

Also I would like to know the "\" in the "FOR" loop represents continue statement or anything else?

Comment: `\\` in the for loop statement is a [deprecated syntax](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements) but it was used to mark the loop "body". These is a specific keyword, [Continue For Loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Continue%20For%20Loop) for continue.

Comment: It works for me in both cases as expected, please update the question with more details as your problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Bence Kaulics. I am using python 2.7.5 and Robot version "Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.5 on linux2)". Might the issue is with the version ? With python 3 it is working fine for me.

Comment: I do not know the reason. But do not use Python 2 anyway stick with Python 3.